# Erro "Function expected" quando usei ngFor para retornar uma string do Firebase, utilizando Ionic 3 e AngularFire2

Tags: ionic, firebase, angular-fire-2

Galera,

Estou usando Ionic3 e Angularfire2 da seguinte maneira. Criei um arquivo .ts chamado servide onde exporto uma função chamana getAll para pegar todos a lista de uma tabela chamada 'cores' no Firebase.

```
 constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {  }
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('cores').valueChanges();
  }`
```

Depois uso o "getAll" em outro momento para buscar a lista

```
export class HomePage {

  private listaCores;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dbService: FirebaseServiceProvider ) {
  this.listaCores = this.dbService.getAll();
  }
```

Quando faço isso vai tudo certo e tal, mas quando tento mostrar o listaCores no app efetivamente com o código abaixo eu tenho um erro "Function Expected".

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of listaCores|async">
      {{c.descCor}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo? Já procurei em diversos lugares e não encontrei efetivamente o problema.

Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Galera, descobri o que eu precisava fazer. Era um problema no rxjs, que precisei fazer um update do 5.5 para o 6.0, visto que o Angular não era compativel com o 5.5.
Utilizei o comado abaixo na pasta do app e foi sucesso:
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save